# Preferred Log Level in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

What is the most preferred log level in production Rails app? I just read in doc that logging has a small impact on production. Currently my log level is set as `info`.

Comment: In reality you want that value to be dynamic. Several ways to do that. Here's a blog I wrote earlier on this 
- https://link.medium.com/5wo7w6E2e6

Answer (score 6):

According to Rails Documentation, available log levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, and :unknown. 
Corresponding to these log level we can use numbers from 0 to 5 respectively.

To set the log level, use

```
config.log_level = :warn  #use on production for a stable release
```

or

```
Rails.logger.level = 0   # for debug
```

Generally the logfiles in production can be use at debug level but once you release or get to a stable version, since we do not want our logfiles to flood our space, we should move it to :warn or :error log level

```
config.log_level = :error  #use on production for a stable release
```

For more info you can check [documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter. You probably don't want it set to `info` if you're storing your logs in a text file on the server but if you're piping all of your logs to a service like Papertrail it shouldn't matter.

That said, you probably won't find the information in `info` particularly useful in Production since you won't be debugging in a live environment.

Comment: I our app We are explicity logging every request and response .Also like this   Rails.logger.info "BackgroundJobConsumer::NoServiceFound payload: #{payload.inspect}"  Does it have significant perfomance issues

Comment: It shouldn't have massive performance issues. If you're running at the sort of scale whereby your logs are causing noticiable performance issues then you should probably hire someone who's job it is to handle logs!